# How to use an IF statement on a Time/Date column to automatically populate a new column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

On my list, I have a Time/Date column named 'ActivityDate'.
The format of this column is "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM"

I am trying to set up a new column called 'Result'.

If the time on 'ActivityDate' is past 9:00 AM, I want the 'Result' column's value to be 'LATE'.

If the time on 'ActivityDate' is before 9:00 AM, I want the 'Result' column's value to be 'ON TIME'.

I am quite familiar with Power Apps / Power Automate, but I have no idea how to set up a formula on sharepoint-column wise.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula for your calculated column:

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR([ActivityDate]),MINUTE([ActivityDate]),SECOND([ActivityDate])) > TIME(9,0,0), "Late", "ON TIME")
```

**Documentation**:

1. [Introduction to SharePoint Formula and Functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-sharepoint-formulas-and-functions-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47)
2. [SharePoint Calculated Field Formula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))

Comment: Hi @dataKim, did you try this? Is it working for you?